# $_GET and $_POST

Tags: php, html, syntax

I have a form and the method is set to post on the action page when I use `$_POST` i dont get the value but if I use `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST` I do.

This does not make sense.  Could someone just clarify it for me?

The code of the form is

```
<form action="create.php" method"POST">
```

Just realized I am missing the = after method.

Comment: Do you see parameters in URL?

Comment: Do you submit the correct form, i.e., are there more forms on the page or even nested form tags? Which Browser do you use? Have you an example site to show?

Comment: can you post the form code and the php code that handles the request?

Comment: Can you post (no pun intended) your HTML form snippet?

Comment: Well, there's something wrong with your code. If you show it to us, we might even be able to tell you *what* is wrong.

Comment: show us the html code of your form

Comment: ...and yes: Does the URL contain the submitted values? Important one from Josef Sábl.

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you use `post` instead of `POST`?

Comment: Really lame question, sorry :-) You should delete it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like you've misplaced or mistyped the method attribute and your form is defaulting to HTTP GET. The form should look like this:

```
<form method="post" action="file.html">
```

Comment: In the code posted you were missing an equals sign after the 'method'. Glad you solved it

Answer (score 1):

What's the `method` set to in the HTML for your form, eg:

```
<form method="POST" ...>
```

Comment: `basically I have a form and the method is set to post` - Don't post questions as answers, that's what comments are for.

Comment: should be in comments, not answers

Comment: heh, and my 'answer' was so far off the mark. Punished for being so quick :)

Answer (score 1):

In PHP ini file, the default setting **GPC (Get, Post, Cookie)** and Request array has that in itself. And make sure that you really the the POST in the action attribute.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you typoed your HTML:

```
<form action="create.php" method"POST">
```

should be

```
<form action="create.php" method="POST">
```

You're missing an equal sign.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="create.php" method="POST">
```

your missing equal sign after the method

Answer (score 1):

POST and GET are different methods to transfer form data, they both use different ways to send the entered values to your application and have to be handled differently. PHP uses $_POST for the values submitted by a form with method="post" and $_GET for values submitted by a form without a method or with method="get". $_REQUEST is a combination of $_POST and $_GET.

The easiest to see difference is:
Parameters submitted with GET appear in the adress bar, i.e.
    http://example.com/index.php?page=home

passes the key page with the value home to $_GET.
Post parameters do not appear in the adress bar.

Answer (score 0):

Your method attribute is wrong, should be:

```
<form action="create.php" method="POST">
```

Answer (score 0):

Hehe :-)

```
<form action="create.php" method="POST">
```

Your sloppy way of writing is not good for coding...

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be the missing "=" :)
BTW, the $_REQUEST variable isn't just a combination of $_POST and $_GET, it's an associative array that by default contains the contents of $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE. ;)